# hp color laser jet printer prints a solid black page

Tags: printing

Recently I bought a new black toner Q6000 cartridge for my hp color laser jet printer. It worked fine at first, but now it will only print a page that is solid black. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Several websites [suggest that](http://www.chaminade.org/mis/Articles/HowLaserPrintersWork.htm) the most likely cause of an all-black page is a damaged primary corona wire.

If it's an HP cartridge, contact HP. They should be able to replace it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This could indicate a problem with your fuser unit, or the photo conductive unit. Look at the care guide (or download one) and perform a full maintenance on your printer as it may be possible just to clean it without purchasing a new one

Answer (score 0):

based on all black on brother [online user guide](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_mfcl2750dw/uke/manual/index.html#GUID-EEC1EE16-C8ED-4BC3-B3C4-27B0AACF0D44_344):
Clean the corona wire inside the drum unit.

The drum unit may be damaged,
Replace the drum unit with a new drum unit.